# Passing onChange from parent overides onChange of the child component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say I have an Input component with `onChange` event handler in it, say count input characters(just to illustrate there's a build-in functionality in that component that I want to use no matter what) and I want to use this Input like across all of my other components:

```
const Input = (props) => {
  const { name, value, countLimit, ...restProps } = props;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const countCharacters = (e) => {
    setCount(e.currentTarget.value.length);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={countCharacters}
        {...restProps}
      />
      <br />
      Count: {count} / {countLimit}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The problem though, is that if I want to pass an `onChange` event handler from outside this component, say to grab some input's value or pass some data from child to parent or something else, it will override this `countCharacters` one. What is the best way to deal with this kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke `props.onChange` (if it exists) from within `countCharacters`:

```
const Input = (props) => {
  const { name, value, countLimit, onChange, ...restProps } = props;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const countCharacters = (e) => {
    setCount(e.currentTarget.value.length);
    onChange?.(e);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={countCharacters}
        {...restProps}
      />
      <br />
      Count: {count} / {countLimit}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, so that's the really best way to handle it? If say I have multiple(nested) component tree and will pass it like that, it shouldn't cause any problems, right? because I always can name the `onChange` handler of the parent as I wish. Am I getting this right?

Comment: So I can do the same on the parent, and on the parent of the parent and so on... and it should be ok, correct?

Comment: Yes, with this pattern you can nest and wrap to your heart's content. Its like a Matryoshka doll of onChange handlers.